# Windsor Castle multiple components for a given service

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have an ILog interface and 2 possible implementations: a console log and a file log. I'm using Windsor Castle in an MVC application therefore i have the following code at controller installer:

```
container.Register(
            Component.For<ILogFactory>().ImplementedBy<LogFactory>().Named("first").OnCreate(x => x.initialize(LogType.Console, null)).LifestyleSingleton(),
            Component.For<ILogFactory>().ImplementedBy<LogFactory>().Named("second").OnCreate(x => x.initialize(LogType.File, null)).LifestyleSingleton(),
            Component.For<ILog>().UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<ILogFactory>("first").GetLog(LogType.Console)).Named("first_log").LifestyleSingleton(),
            Component.For<ILog>().UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<ILogFactory>("second").GetLog(LogType.File)).Named("second_log").LifestyleSingleton()
        );
```

In my TestController i have the following code:

```
private ILog log;

public TestController(ILog _log)
{
    log = _log;
}
```

I'm wondering HOW i could decide to inject the ILog named first_log or second_log

Comment: A unit test normally has 1 class under test and 0 to many fake classes (mocks or stubs). You don't test a DI configuration - that is part of your application - generally you don't use a DI container with a unit test. So, assuming `TestController` is a mock, what is the class under test in this scenario? If you are testing a specific logger or a specific log factory, you should be creating an instance of it in your test with the `new` keyword.

Comment: This is not a unit test: i just named the controller TestController but you can call it myController or whatever you want. I'm just wondering how in this controller, i could handle the log that i want to inject based on its name

Comment: When it comes to logging, It's more usual to have a single implementation of the logging component (`ILog`) and configuration is used to determine at run time where it should log - file, console, database, etc - and at what level - debug, warning, error, etc. That allows your logging configuration to be changed without recompiling your code. Log4net is a good example of this.

Comment: Thanks, actually this example maybe was a little bit misleading; i used a logging example but the goal was a little bit different, that is: how to inject into the controller, the interface based on its name... this is still something i cannot handle

Comment: I don't see the registration of your TestController in the Register methode. Can you add it ?

Comment: @Marwijn what do you mean?

Comment: It is these kinds of cases that make [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) a better alternative than using a DI container IMO. See this article for more details: http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my scenario. The TestController needs the 2 ILogs defined:

```
public class TestController : Controller 
{ 
private ILog log1; 
private ILog log2; 

public TestController(ILog _log1, ILog _log2) 
{ 
log1 = _log1; 
log2 = _log2; 
identifier = _identifier; 
}
```

Then it is necessary to add:

```
container.Register(
Component.For<MyController>().DependsOn(
 ServiceOverride.ForKey("_log1").Eq("first_log"),
 ServiceOverride.ForKey("_log2").Eq("second_log")).LifestyleTransient()
 );
```

replacing the actual default content:

```
container.Register(
 Classes.
 FromThisAssembly().
 BasedOn<IController>().
 If(c => c.Name.EndsWith("Controller")).
 LifestyleTransient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.

You could use a subdependency resolver. It allows you resolve a specific component for a dependency of another componennt. the code belows should (not tested) resolve the ILog based on the name of the parameter in the constructor of the TestController.
So TestController (ILog first) will resolve the ILog named first.

```
class SubDepResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
  private IKernel kernel;
  SubDepResolver(IKernel kernel)
  {
    this.kernel = kernel;
  }

  public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model,
    DependencyModel dependency)
  {
    if (model.GetComponentType() != typeof(TestController)) return false;
    if (dependency.GetComponentType() != typeof(ILog)) return false;
    return true;
  }

  public object Resolve(
    CreationContext context, 
    ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, 
    ComponentModel model,
    DependencyModel dependency)
  {
    var handlers = kernel.GetHandlers(typeof(ILog));
    var handler = handlers.Single(h => h.GetComponentName() == dependency.DependencyKey);
    return handler.Resolve(context);
  }
}
```

Add the resolver using :

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new SubDepResolver(container.Kernel));
```

Good luck,
Marwijn.